# Can Mavericks Spaces support 3 windows spanned across 2 displays?

Tags: macos, display, spaces

Is it possible to have a 3-screen Space across two displays such that you can swipe to toggle between seeing displays 1 & 2 or 2 & 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

In Mavericks, each space (or full-screen application) can be assigned to any screen, and the 4-finger-swipe gesture will slide between spaces/apps on that screen only.

You can see this quite clearly if you open up Mission Control with multiple monitors; each monitor's spaces/apps are shown across the top of said monitor.

So, for example, you could put Desktop 1 and Desktop 2 on your left monitor, Desktop 3 on your right monitor. Swiping on your left monitor would change between Desktops 1 & 2, while the right monitor would remain on Desktop 3.

Comment: Maybe that's as close as I'll get, but what I was looking for was the ability to toggle between L:1/R:2 and L:2/R:3 (as opposed to L:1/R:3 and L:2/R:3). Or for a 4-screen/2-display config: L:1/R:2, L:2/R:3, and L:3/R:4, and so on. The idea is that the screens are static relative to each other, and the N-display window would also stay fixed as it slides across views.

Comment: Ah, no I don't think you can do that. There's an option for "Displays have separate spaces", but I believe that just reverts to the old (Mountain Lion) behaviour. You might find some software which can be scripted to change both screens to specific spaces at once, to customise the movements... but I'm not aware of any.